Continuity of an oscillatory type function
I'm learning calculus, and it seems like I'm confused with the basic laws of math. Take a function $x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$. Is it continuous at $x=0$?. The limit of the function is $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$ indeed, but is the function defined at $x=0$? Directly plugging in $x=0$ gives us $0*\sin(\frac{1}{0})$. Is that equal to $0$, or undefined?? $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, so according to me this value has to be undefined, but my teachers say this value is $0$. Please clarify this, with simple yet convincing explanation.

It is undefined. The question that we usually like to ask, as adapted to this situation, is the following:
Is there some real number $c$ such that if we define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} c & x=0 \\ x \sin(1/x) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
then that $f$ is continuous?
The answer to that is yes, and that $c$ is $0$. This $f$ with $c=0$ is a continuous extension of $x \sin(1/x)$.
Mathematicians and teachers sometimes abuse notation by using the description of the "unextended" function to refer to the extended function, but it is not technically correct to do that, so they should not do it when there is any risk of being misunderstood.
On the flip side, a lot of the time when we say things like "$1/x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$", what we really mean is "$1/x$ can't be continuously extended to $x=0$", since $1/x$ is already not defined at $x=0$ anyway. Again we technically shouldn't talk like that, but sometimes we do.
There are lots of such tricky domain issues that come up often. Some of them interfere with our impulses from algebra. For example $x \mapsto x/x$ is not the function that maps all real numbers to $1$, but rather the function that maps all real numbers except for $0$ to $1$. So silently writing $x/x=1$ is actually wrong as well.
